# AWS EKS Fargate and Nodegroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have an AWS EKS with Fargate Profiles and Nodegroup with EC2 instances. I have a Fargate Profile that select "kube-system" namespace.

[image]

1. For some reason `kube-proxy` POD is running under Nodegroup and not fargate, and this POD is under kube-system namespace.  I noted that all pods with type DaemonSet is running under Nodegroup, and ignoring Fargate Profile. Any explanation for this? I didn't found in AWS Docs.
2. How to configure AWS EKS to deploy a specific POD to nodegroup instead fargate, under 'kube-system' namespace (remeber that I have a fargate profile with kube-system selector).

Answer (score 0):

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html -

> Daemonsets are not supported on Fargate. If your application requires a daemon, you should reconfigure that daemon to run as a sidecar container in your pods.

2. To schedule deployment of AWS EKS pod to Fargate you simply provide pod selector for particular namespace e.g for namespace `kube-system` create pod selector `computation-mode: fargate` in AWS UI or by any CLI. Then you need to provide this `computation-mode: fargate` label to every k8s controller e.g `deployment` for AWS EKS to know that you want to use Fargate solution.

So answering your question:

> How to configure AWS EKS to deploy a specific POD to nodegroup instead fargate

Just do not provide any pod selector on k8s controller. But remember that if you do not have ANY pod selector on fargate profile for a particular namespace then by default all pods should TRY to do it by Fargate.

Hope it makes any sense.